# How do I root a phone without losing any data?

Tags: samsung, rooting, samsung-galaxy-s-4

I don't care if my phone trips the knox counter, I couldn't care any less if samsung knows I tried to root my phone but I'm tired of looking at videos on YouTube that say "This method works without any app and data loss", I used CFAutoroot and that erased my device. You all know how to root a phone teach me, I want to be able to keep my apps and data not lose any apps while rooting my phone. I was able to root only one phone with Android KitKat, without losing any apps except for Google Chrome, I want to root a phone with no app loss.